# I keep getting same errors when trying to rerun Telethon script

Tags: python, telethon

so i`m trying to learn Telethon and wrote some script from tutorial. It works fine for the first time, when i have to confirm authorization.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 1234567
api_hash = ''
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.username)
    

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

but when i try to run it again with the same .session file i keep getting same error, which doesn`t help to understand the problem.

```
Server sent a very new message with ID 7144059125492611077, ignoring
Server sent a very new message with ID 7144059125964561409, ignoring
```

Also, program doesn`t stop running after this error.

Comment: Relevant, did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628446/error-messages-clogging-telethon-resulting-in-security-error-server-sent-a-very

Comment: I saw it, but the answer doesn`t resolve the problem, they say to just delete the .session file every time before running code, which requires to confirm authorization, and telegram have a maximum of 5 authorizations per day.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days searching for a fix, i just switched to pyrogram, which works perfectly fine. So if someone got the same problem I recommend just to change Telethon to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system time is correct. If the issue persists, it may be a bug you which you should report to https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/new/choose. However recent versions of the library (v1.25.2) should not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your server/pc time.

1. Type this command in terminal.

   sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
2. Select continent & city.
3. Done!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: BUT WHAT TO CHOOSE ???!!