# Server sent a very new message with ID

Tags: telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
# I used my own api key from my.telegram.org

with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
```

Even running this small code snippet is giving me this error message.

```
Server sent a very new message with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ignoring (see FAQ for details)
Server sent a very new message with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ignoring (see FAQ for details)
```

I have had no such issue before. But now whenever I execute any code all I receive is this error message. I checked the solutions provided in the FAQ, everything seems fine. I am only using this session on my machine (I tried creating new sessions), I am not using any proxy, and the Date and time is correct (and is set to automatic).

After that the terminal gets clogged with the earlier message and `Security error while unpacking a received message: Too many messages had to be ignored consecutively`.

#### I tried

- I tried creating new sessions. After removing all files with `*.session`, when I try to login again the code works. But when I run the code again after that, it shows this message.
- I tried running it on a cloud machine that I have access to. Everything is working fine.
- I tried re-installing all the packages (just in case).

#### FYI

- I am using Ubuntu 22.04
- telethon 1.34.0
- Python 3.9.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error messages clogging Telethon resulting in security error: Server sent a very new message xxxxx was ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628446/error-messages-clogging-telethon-resulting-in-security-error-server-sent-a-very)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. There was some seconds difference in PC time and actual time, so even setting the automatic date and time update option in Ubuntu doesn't seem to be updating my time.
I force updating the date & time I used
`sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"`.
This fixed my problem in Ubuntu.

Comment: [If you have the Automatic Date & Time switch set to on, your date and time should update automatically if you have an internet connection. To update your date and time manually, set this to off.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/clock-set.html.en#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20the%20Automatic%20Date%20%26%20Time%20switch%20set%20to%20on%2C%20your%20date%20and%20time%20should%20update%20automatically%20if%20you%20have%20an%20internet%20connection.%20To%20update%20your%20date%20and%20time%20manually%2C%20set%20this%20to%20off)